# Finding convexhull in an image using opencv and c++?

Tags: c++, opencv

i am new to opencv and i was following the tutorials that are posted in docs.opencv.org. I was checking out this program which explained how to find the convex hull in an image.
I couldnot understand this very part of the program.

*vector > contours;*

*vector hierarchy;*

what does these two lines mean?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In the [Documentation of findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) you should find all the information you are looking for. Basically, contours is a vector of the contours each of which is a vector of points (you can define a policy which points should be retrieved from the contour: all points or only corner points etc.) with the 'method' parameter. hierarchy is a vector containing 4 indices for each contour, the index of the next and previous contours on the same level, the first child and the parent respectively. There's also a 'mode' parameter that defines the behavior of the contour detection with nested contours. I hope this helps.

Edit: Btw, you should always link the souce you are referring to, I assume it is [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html)?

Comment: I am sorry for not linking the tutorial.http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html

Comment: @ user3893569-@user3893569 - I am sorry for not linking the tutorial.Here is the link----http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html. bdw i couldnot get the hierachy part. Please can you explain me in a simplified way if possible.

Comment: I will try it with a simple example: Let us assume we have 5 rectangles, R1, R2 etc. No 2 rectangles intersect. R2 and R3 are contained in R1 and R5 is contained in R4. Let us assume contours are the contours ordered as {R1 R2 R3 R4 R5}. Then hierarchy would be {{-1, 4, 2, -1}, {-1, 3, -1, 1}, {2, -1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, 5, -1}, {-1, -1, -1, 4}}. For each rectangle, hierarchy contains a 4D-point {w, x, y, z} where w is index of previous rectangle on same level, x index of next rectangle on same level, y index of first rectangle on level below, z index of parent. -1 for 'NULL'. Is it clear now?

Comment: Drawing the example on a sheet may help you... And also make sure you read the documentation link for findContours I provided above: [link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours)

Comment: :- Thanks for your help. I totally understood it. I actually wanted a suggestion. I am a freshman engineering student and i have a good idea about c++. My interest has always been about computer vision and robotics. So, i started using the tutorials posted in docs.opencv.org. Is that a good idea or do i have to do some background study before jumping into computer vision? Thank u again.

Comment: Generally, I would definitely suggest that you also take some basic courses at your university that are related to computer vision, visual computing, image processing etc. I have myself taken only one course in visual computing and am now doing my bachelor thesis in this field. I have to look up many things in books or online courses. The OpenCV docs alone do not help much. They often only describe, what a certain function does, not what it can be used for. So you should first know what you want to use for your application, then look up in OpenCV docs how you can achieve that using OpenCV :)

Comment: Thanks for your advise . I really appreciate it. The problem is that i am in my 2nd semester and most computer vision courses are in the 400 level courses and for doing that i have to be atleast a junior and senior. I am crazy interested in this field and i am finding really hard to wait until that time. I want to develop a gesture based application that can recognise my gestures and do certain activities. What's your suggestion for this?

Comment: My advisor for my bachelor thesis participated to a gesture recognition on smartphones project where they built an app to control maps, books, games etc. on the smartphone with gestures which were recorded by the smarphone's camera and then processed on GPU. According to him is a really tricky topic so you will probably have to wait until you are senior :) If you don't want to wait, you probably have to educate yourself outside of university, there are plenty of papers and probably also books. Sorry that I can't help you more with this.

Comment: I also cannot recommend you any concrete books and papers in this particular field since I don't know any, but I guess you should start with some basic stuff. Papers are often very concrete in describing what they do, but to really understand the underlying techniques and especially the math, you probably can't get out of learning some basics (and it is probably quite a lot of math) first.

Comment: @user3893569---Thanks for your help.You are right. I am trying to educate myself as much as i can. The best part about the computer vision programs are the algorithms. I mean i love maths but never thought that maths can be used to manipulate maths. It fascinates me so much. I am simply following the tutorials at docs.opencv.org nd i am using c++. Should i stick to c++ or do i have to switch to another programming language like MATLAB or python? Whts your suggestion?

Comment: :-I also dint understand the meaning of this line Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( src_binary.size(), CV_8UC3 ); I am confused what does the zeros mean in the code. Also, what does the whole concept of scalar mean in opencv? Like scalar value declaration at the beginning of my code. What does it mean? http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html